# What is the source for the differences of coverings between a Sephardic and Ashkenazik Sefer Torah

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, sefer-torah

Typically an Ashkenazik Sefer Torah (image 1) scroll is covered first by a cloth binding ('gartel') and then a cloth cover. a Sephardic Sefer Torah (image 2) is typically enclosed in a wooden box. Is this purely a logistical happenstance that evolved over time or are there any religious reasons for these different approaches to covering the Torah in these different ways?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The answer is here: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3119530/jewish/Why-Do-Sephardim-Keep-Their-Torahs-in-Cylindrical-Cases.htm